# Weighted directed graph in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I want to create a directed graph with weights in netlogo. I searched documentions but I couldn't find a way to put weights on my links. Here is my code:

```
to setup
  clear-all                       ;; clear everything on canvas
  setup-nodes                     ;; a procedure to set nodes
  setup-edges                     ;; a procedure to set edges
  ask turtles [ set color red]    ;; paint nodes red
  ask links [set color white]     ;; paint edges white
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-nodes
  set-default-shape turtles "circle"
  crt number-of-nodes ;; users give this number from the interface
  [
    ; for visual reasons, we don't put any nodes *too* close to the edges
    setxy (random-xcor * 0.95) (random-ycor * 0.95)
  ]
end

to setup-edges
  while [ count links < num-links ] ;; num-links given by the user from interface
  [
    ask one-of turtles 
    [
      let choice one-of other turtles

      if choice != nobody [ create-link-to choice ]
    ] 
  ]
    ; make the network look a little prettier
    repeat 10
    [
      layout-spring turtles links 0.3 (world-width / (sqrt number-of-nodes)) 1
    ]
end
```

Comment: as I cannot find an example with links-own, could you please tell me, where exactly put it in my code? I try under the  "if choice != ...." but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`links-own [weight]` (at the top of the Code tab) adds a variable named `weight` to links.

Some models in the NetLogo Models Library that use `links-own`: Small Worlds, Team Assembly, Diffusion on a Directed Network, Artificial Neural Net, Link Breeds Example, Network Import Example.